# Contraction of (non-prime) ideals in integral extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, integral-extensions

If $A \subset B$ is an integral extension, then any prime $p \subset A$ is the contraction of some prime of $B$ (by lying-over property). Does this hold for more general ideals? That is, given an ideal $I \subset A$, is there always an ideal $J \subset B$ such that $I = J^c$ ?

If not, do we at least have $I^{ec} = I$ for all ideals $I$ of $A$? Possibly if we assume that $A \subset B$ is of finite type (hence finite)?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a remark: if $I=J^c$ then $I=I^{ec}$. So the two claims are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to all your questions is no; a simple counterexample is the integral extension of finite type $\Bbb{Z}[2i]\subset\Bbb{Z}[i]$ with the ideal $(2)\subset\Bbb{Z}[2i]$. Then $(2)^{ec}$ contains the element
$$2\cdot i=2i,$$
but $2i$ is not contained in $(2)\subset\Bbb{Z}[2i]$. So we have $(2)^{ec}\neq(2)$. It easily follows that $(2)\subset\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ is not the contraction of any ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you have an example where $I^e$ is prime in $B$?

Comment: Sure; simply replace all $2$'s by $3$'s in the example; the ideal $(3)\subset\Bbb{Z}[3i]$ does the trick.