# Principal non-prime ideal whose extension is prime

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A \subset B$ be a finite extension of integral domains. Let $(a)$ be a principal ideal in $A$. If $(a)^e = aB$ is a prime ideal of $B$, does it follow that $(a)$ is prime in $A$ ?

I have a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980727), but the given example doesn't work.

Comment: Another example is given in this comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980727/contraction-of-non-prime-ideals-in-integral-extensions/2980788#comment6152419_2980788

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. Take $A = k[x,xy,xy^2,y^3] \subset B = k[x,y]$. The ideal $xA$ is not prime, but $xB$ is; $x(xy^2) = (xy)^2$, but $xy \notin xA$ in $A$.