# Is $\Bbb Z[i]$ flat as $\Bbb Z[2i]$-module?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, flatness

Is $\Bbb Z[i]$ flat as $\Bbb Z[2i]$-module ? (Here $i^2 = -1$).

I know it's flat as a $\Bbb Z$-module, since it is torsion-free and $\Bbb Z$ is Dedekind. Actually it is even free as $\Bbb Z$-module. But I don't think that $\Bbb Z[i]$ is free over $\Bbb Z[2i]$.

I think that it is not faithfully flat : [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980727), we have an ideal $I \subset \Bbb Z[2i]$ such that $I \neq I^{ec}$. But I don't know if this is because it is not flat or not faithful.

Comment: I believe it is flat, judging from the last criterion on [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module#Commutative_rings), but unfortunately I cannot write up an answer at the moment. Use that the image of any map $\Bbb{Z}[2i]^n\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[i]$ is always $\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ or $0$.

Comment: One thing is that $\mathbb{Z}[2i]$ is Noetherian and thus "flat $\iff$ projective" for finitely generated case.

Comment: Note that $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ is flat over $\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ if and only if $\Bbb{Z}[i]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is flat over $\Bbb{Z}[2i]_{\mathfrak{p}}$ for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}\subset\Bbb{Z}[2i]$. This is obviously true for every prime $\mathfrak{p}$ not containing $2$ as then the two localizations are the same, hence it remains to check this for the unique prime $\mathfrak{p}=(2,2i)\subset\Bbb{Z}[2i]$ lying over $2$.

Comment: Didn't think too much about it but is $2i \otimes 1 + 2 \otimes -i$ nonzero in $(2) \otimes \mathbb{Z}[i]$? If so flatness fails.

Comment: Yes, it is not flat since it is integral, and integral + flat implies faithfully flat (which you know that doesn't hold).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close this up and generalize a little bit... using user26857's approach in the comments, we can show that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not flat over $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$ for any prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$.

> **Lemma** $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$.

**Proof**: Let $z = a + ib \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Consider the imaginary component of $(a + ib)^p$. Using the binomial formula, we get an expression for it as $\sum\limits_{k=1 \\ \text{k odd}}^p (-1)^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}a^{p-k}b^k{p \choose k}$.  If $p$ is odd, this reduces to $(-1)^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} b^p \text{ mod } p$ (since ${p \choose k}$ is divisible by $p$ for $k \not= 0, p$).  From Fermat's little theorem, we see that $z^p - (-1)^{\lfloor p/2 \rfloor}z \in \mathbb{Z}[pi]$, so that $z$ is integral over $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$.  Otherwise $p = 2$ and we have $z^2 \in \mathbb{Z}[2i]$.

> **Lemma**: A flat integral extension is faithfully flat.

**Proof**: Integral extensions [satisfy lying over](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00GQ) for primes, so the induced map on spectra will be surjective.  In the presence of flatness, [this is equivalent to faithful flatness](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HQ).

> **Lemma**: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not faithfully flat over $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$

**Proof**: As in your linked question, we note that faithfully flat extension are such that ideals are preserved by extension-contraction. We establish that $(p) \subset \mathbb{Z}[pi]$ is such that $(p)^{ec} \not= (p)$ by noting that $pi \in (p)^{ec}$ but $pi \notin (p)$

> **Conclusion**.  For any prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is not flat over $\mathbb{Z}[pi]$